# Importing modules with or without forRoot

Tags: angular

Most Angular 2+ libraries including `ng-bootstrap` provides modules that should be imported. Sometimes they have `forRoot()` method, sometimes not.

Recently I was struggling with a bug caused by importing a `NgbDatepickerModule` in a submodule of my application with `NgbDatepickerModule.forRoot()`...,  removing `forRoot` solved the issue.

I guess `forRoot` method should be only called when importing module to which is entry point to application and also has `BrowserModule`? But modules can be later imported to submodules, which I guess should be done without `forRoot` call.

Why? What is the difference in module creation when module is created via `forRoot` or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.forFoot()` method is created manually by modules' developers and is intended to be used just once in main module imports. This method is supposed to return `ModuleWithProviders`, what is:

```
export interface ModuleWithProviders {
    ngModule: Type<any>;
    providers?: Provider[];
}
```

You can see that in case of [`NgbDatepickerModule`](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/datepicker/datepicker.module.ts) it looks this way:

```
export class NgbDatepickerModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: NgbDatepickerModule,
      providers: [
        {provide: NgbCalendar, useClass: NgbCalendarGregorian},
        {provide: NgbDatepickerI18n, useClass: NgbDatepickerI18nDefault},
        {provide: NgbDateParserFormatter, useClass: NgbDateISOParserFormatter}, NgbDatepickerConfig
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

When you used this method also in a submodule, then those providers got overridden by new instances, what could lead to unexpected behaviour.